# Weird IntelliSense with generic methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a code like this:

```
void F(bool a, bool b) { }
void F(int a) { }
int G<T1, T2>(int a) { return 1; }
class A { }
class B { }

void Main(string[] args)
{
    int G = 1;
    int A = 1;
    int B = 1;

    F(G<A, B>(7));      // call F(int a)
    F(G<A, B>(7 / 3));  // call F(int a)
    F(G<A, B>3);        // call F(bool a, bool b)
}
```

But when I put the mouse over the `A` on the third call in the `Main` function, it says it is `class Sample.Program.A` instead of `(local variable) int A`. Why was it like this?

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional in framework 4. Is it the same with your IntelliSense?

---

For those who don't immediately understand the third line `F(G<A, B>3);`

It is `F(` `G < A` `,` `B > 3` `);`

Where `G < A` is bool and `B > 3` is also bool and that function is calling the `void F(bool a, bool b)` method.

---

The purpose of this code is for educational purposes only that's why it is like that. But the IntelliSense is not working right at the third line `F(G<A, B>3);`.

Comment: It looks like the code serves its educational purpose - even people who deal with parsing code (which is what intellisence is based on) make bugs. You are welcome to report bug (VS->Help->Report bug or http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Is it the same case with you? I am just not sure if it is a bug or is it just because of my VS so I'm not yet reporting it as a bug. Have you try it in your VS too?

Comment: If this were really IntelliSense bug, I doubt that MS would really fix it, or even care about it. I also object that this question is about the specific tool not the language itself, so it should involve real life code instead of pure 'educational' code.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, T1, T2 is a type name itself so it is absolutely not be a variable so the feature IntelliSense is working right.

Comment: Yeap, I'm not quite sure why you think Intellisense is working wrong

Comment: when you compile codebase did it has any warnings ? I test your case in Mono so the Intellisense is working right even I have basic code `void main() {... int a = 1; int b = 2; int c = 3; F(a < b, b > c); ... }` Intellisense has a warning "c is a symbol not defined" however I think Intellisense working based on metadata information and it compile your code when you're coding

Comment: I am not sure about Mono, have you try to copy and paste my code inside a class in a namespace and try to compile it? Doe's your IntelliSense works fine? It should say `(local variable) int A` in the line `F(G<A, B>3);` in `A`.

Comment: It didn't tell me what A is whether local variable or class because of warning "unexpected symbol '3'"